# How to do filter and map without overhead of repeating operation

Tags: java, performance, java-stream

I have some cases where using Java 8 Stream makes me repeat the execution of some operation where it could be avoided if done without the Stream, but I think that the problem is not with the stream, but me.

Some example:

```
private class Item {
    String id;
    List<String> strings;
}

// This method, filters only the Items that have the strToFind, and
// then maps it to a new string, that has the id and the str found
private void doIt(List<Item> items, String strToFind) {
    items.stream().filter(item -> {
        return item.strings.stream().anyMatch(str -> this.operation(str, strToFind));
    }).map(item -> {
        return item.id + "-" + item.strings.stream()
            .filter(str -> this.operation(str, strToFind)).findAny().get();
    });
}

// This operation can have a lot of overhead, therefore
// it would be really bad to apply it twice
private boolean operation(String str, String strToFind) {
    return str.equals(strToFind);
}
```

As you can see, the function `operation` is being called twice for each item, and I don't want that. What I thought first was to map directly and return "null" if not found and then filter nulls, but if I do that, I will lose the reference to the Item and therefore, can't use the id.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a cleverer option but right after `map`-then-`filter` like you suggested came the idea of using `reduce` to selectively transform and push to a new list.

Comment: In this case, `item.strings.stream().filter(str -> this.operation(str, strToFind)).findAny().get()` could be replaced by `strToFind`, but I guess that `operation` is not actually implemented like that?

Comment: @JornVernee right, I put an `equals` to just represent a operation, but that could be different stuff. I didn't put the original code because is a lot of code..

Comment: I find it much easier to read this without horizontal scrolling but if you object feel free to revert my edit.

Comment: @DavidConrad No problem! I find it easier too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
private void doIt(List<Item> items, String strToFind) {
    items.stream()
         .flatMap(item -> item.strings.stream().unordered()
             .filter(str -> this.operation(str, strToFind)).limit(1)
             .map(string -> item.id + "-" + string))
         // example terminal operation
         .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The `.unordered()` and `.limit(1)` exist to produce the same behavior like `anyMatch()` and `findAny()` of your original code. Of course, `.unordered()` is not required to get a correct result.

In Java 9, you could also use

```
private void doIt(List<Item> items, String strToFind) {
    items.stream()
         .flatMap(item -> item.strings.stream()
             .filter(str -> this.operation(str, strToFind))
             .map(string -> item.id + "-" + string).findAny().stream())
         // example terminal operation
         .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

keeping the `findAny()` operation, but unfortunately, Java 8 lacks the `Optional.stream()` method and trying to emulate it would create code less readable than the `limit(1)` approach.

Comment: I think this solution is better because you don't have to thinks like returning null and stuff like that. Very elegant !

Answer (score 5):

I think you might want this behaviour :

```
items.stream().map(item -> {
        Optional<String> optional = item.strings.stream().filter(string -> operation(string, strToFind)).findAny();
        if(optional.isPresent()){
            return item.id + "-" + optional.get();
        }
        return null;
    }).filter(e -> e != null);
```

EDIT :
Because you're losing the information obtained in the filter when you're doing the map afterwards, but nothing prevents you from doing the operation in the map only and filtering afterwards.

EDIT 2 : 
As @Jorn Vernee pointed out, you can shorten it further :

```
private void doIt(List<Item> items, String strToFind) {
    items.stream().map(item -> item.strings.stream().filter(string -> operation(string, strToFind)).findAny()
            .map(found -> item.id + "-" + found).orElse(null)).filter(e -> e != null);
}
```

Comment: You could replace the `if` and `return` with  `return optional.map(str -> item.id + "-" + str).orElse(null)`. Or make the whole thing a one-liner.

Comment: @Jorn Vernee Very true, I hadn't looked it up that far.

Answer (score 2):

Although not the shortest code (but this has not been asked for) I believe this works quite straightforward using `Optional` but does not involve any `null` mappings and/or checks and type information (String vs. Object) is not accidentally lost:

```
items.stream()
    .map(item -> item.strings.stream()
        .filter(str -> this.operation(str, strToFind))
        .findAny()
        .<String>map(string -> item.id + "-" + string))
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get);
```

It's pretty much a combination of Jeremy Grand's and Holger's answers.